# How do I use is_tag on a post in WordPress's archive.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to add a particular thing to everyone post on my blog based on that posts tags.

On my category pages especially. So I'm in my archive.php file and I want to use if (`is_tag()`) to print some stuff based on if the tag is there.

The problem is of course that its not working. I'm assuming its because I can't use the `is_tag` on non tag pages?

Answer (score 1):

[`is_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag) tells you whether the page being viewed is a tag archive page (a page that lists posts by tag). It is not a function to retrieve the tags for a post. Use [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper usage is [`has_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (has_tag()) { ?>
tags available
<?php } else { ?>
no tags
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!